# Adding a source file(that contains global variables and functions) to main file without creating a header for it?(for code clarity)

Tags: c

I'm trying to build an embedded C program and got to a point where it contains more than a 1000 lines and growing in ESP IDF using CMAKE which makes the code hard to read and debug because of all the scrolling so I'm trying to split it into more files like my_funcs.c that will include global structs(variables) and function that I want to access from main without creating a header file for it my_funcs.h since the the values of the variables there should not duplicate (from #include from file to file)

So the question is:
is making such code extensions and split possible? if so how'd you do that with CMAKE?
if not how do professional programmers confront with such cases when code gets so long?

I Could start making header files for the source files and work more with pointers but this seem way harder than it can and should be and still doesn't solve the problem of saving the config_t structs separately from main.c

Comment: I have the feeling that threating those external source files as regular "libraries" and create a header is the way to do it in C (as long as you can use global variables in there too never tried it) this still just seem too much work but I still need some confirmation from the more advanced programmer in here before I go "out of standard" and start wasting my time of creating additional header files that might not be necessary.

Comment: Why don't you want to make a header for it?  That's the way that information gets shared between source files in C, via headers that are included both where the declared objects are defined and where they are used.  Headers are the glue that hold multi-file programs together.

Comment: Before you do that; read this: https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/.  You seem also to have a very strange idea about modular programming and multiple module compilation and linking.  Why would you not want to use a header file?  Unless you mean simply to place the code in a header file and include it - you should certainly not do that - header files should be _declarative_ only - declaring code that exists in _separate translation units_.  It seems you question should simply be about adding code modules to an ESP IDF Cmake project?

Comment: Most of the guys that teach C teach libraries in a way that makes them look like they are only good for when you need to duplicate the code in them in many places rather than for local single use code simplification so it deceives and including libraries "twice" just for "hiding and moving code" seem in efficient as I want those functions to access variables from main the same way as if they were written in the main.c file in the same scope without modifying the whole system to pointer based which takes more planning and more work.

Comment: @Clifford I was actually thinking of doing something similar and try to include my global struct configs like:
i2c_dev_t MyRTC = {

  .port = I2C_NUM_0,
  .addr = RTC_ADDR,
  .cfg.sda_io_num = I2C_SDA_PIN,
  .cfg.scl_io_num = I2C_SCL_PIN,
  .cfg.master.clk_speed = 400000,}; 

in there(if it'll work) to hide it from me since It's a set and forget struct config and I don't need it to disturb me while debugging the user interface and the rest of the stuff.

Comment: Header files != Libraries BTW - you need header files for external module declarations - those external modules need not be library code.

Comment: @Clifford My definition of a library is a folder that adds functionality to a code with a Source .c and a header .h file. don't realy get your last phrase.

Comment: @Pongo — I think what Clifford was saying is that you can have external modules in object files that are not formally in a library (shared object or static archive).   However, you need to list such modules explicitly in the linking lines if they are not in a library.

Comment: "Library" normally refers to a statically linked (.lib or .a) or a dynamically linked (.dll or .so) collection of object code.  It is you who is using the term atypically.  Any non-trivial program would (should) comprise multiple modules of C code compiled to object code and linked.  The organisation is not necessarily about code reuse but also maintainability and comprehensibility, and for large applications to support incremental, distributed and multi-threaded compilation for faster builds.

Comment: @Pongo — Note that a 'folder' (directory in POSIX parlance) is not a library — a library is either a shared object (DLL on Windows) or a static archive.  A library may hold one or many object files.  Often, the source for a library is held in a single folder.  But that is not mandated — you can have multiple folders contributing to a single library, or a single folder contributing to multiple libraries.

Comment: Your don't in any case `include libraries twice`; you simply include the declarative header file - the object code is linked exactly _once_ (whether it is from a static-link library or simply the object code from a separate translation unit - which is _still_ not a library).

Comment: w.r.t. "_ I was actually thinking of doing something similar_" I am not sure what you are referring to.  The link I posted was not intended in any way to answer your question; rather to point out why you _should not_ even have _global variables_ in the first instance.  The article discusses why, and solutions to the problem.  One reason for separate compilation units is to achieve loose coupling and tight cohesion - you can't have that _and_ have global variables.

Comment: Anyhow, the question is being discussed a lot but you have not clarified it such that it might be answered - you have provided a great deal of distracting information (for example perhaps we did not need to know about your global data?).  You need to edit the question in light of the comments I think.  Try not to make it an X-Y problem; explain your actual problem, and ask for a solution - currently you are describing your _solution_ and asking how to implement it.

Comment: I am still not clear what your question is - specifically the "_without creating a header for it_" part, but the way to add modules to the Cmake project is discussed at https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=14362.  You don't actually need a header file -`#include` is simply an in-line text replacement with the content of the file; you can place the `extern` declarations directly in the source referencing external symbols.  The header file is a useful way however of ensuring that the declaration and the definition match - is it really such a hardship to create one?

Comment: My general question was referring more to the problem of how programmers deal with ending up with a long code and then compressing and splitting it into other files without enginnering a system to send data between function for the variables declared in a local scope in main.c the closest thing that can achieve it that I know of in C is by putting the code I want to compress in a header file including the variables and include them in that local scope In main like that without a source file: 
void rtosFunc(){

  while(true){
    #include "my_funcs.h"
  }
}

Comment: Why would the programmers community hate me for that?